# Use a Marker InfoClickListener interface

Tags: android, interface, listener, xamarin, google-maps-markers

I am using Xamarin and am wanting to handle clicks on a Google Map Marker InfoWindow. I have done some research and I need to use an OnInfoWindowClickListener.

Here is my current code:

```
_map.SetOnInfoWindowClickListener (onInfoWindowClickListener);
```

And the method I have written to cater to the clicks is this:

```
private void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker)
{
    Toast.MakeText (this, String.Format ("InfoWindow is Clicked"), ToastLength.Short).Show ();
}
```

This is the error I am getting:

> The name 'onInfoWindowClickListener' does not exist in the current
>   context

Can I please have some help with this code?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Here is the class code:

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/activity_label_mapwithmarkers")]
public class MapWithMarkersActivity : Activity
{
     //long code goes here
}
```

I think that I need to implement this interface:

```
GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener
```

Yet I am not sure how via code...

Comment: your class extend to what, activity or fragment, or is a simple class?

Comment: I have not extended my class, can I have some help to do this?

Comment: So you mean that its a simple class, can you show this class code?

Comment: Can you have a look at my edit?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a Listener to a Google Map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21215572/adding-a-listener-to-a-google-map)

Comment: I just answered this same question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21219616/165093.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about Xamarin, but in android, we do like this-

```
        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You clicked !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: The error happens even before the method is called. The toast is just there to add some code to the method.

Comment: Can you help me implement the interface? I think this is the problem.

Comment: are you getting this kind of error on setting other listensers on map?

Comment: I am not even sure how to set any listeners on a map. Can you please explain how to do this?

Comment: I have tried that code but it does not work in Xamarin. I will ask a new question for this answer expressly in Xamarin.