# Adding a Listener to a Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, interface, listener, xamarin

In Xamarin, how do I add an OnInfoWindowClickListener to a Google map?

I have read that:

> You can use an OnInfoWindowClickListener to listen to click events on
>   an info window. To set this listener on the map, call
>   GoogleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(OnInfoWindowClickListener).
>   When a user clicks on an info window, onInfoWindowClick(Marker) will
>   be called

The resource is here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows

This is the interface code I have added:

```
public interface onInfoWindowClickListener {
    void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker);
}
```

I have added this method:

```
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker)
{
    //Toast.MakeText (MapWithMarkersActivity.this, String.Format ("InfoWindow is Clicked"), ToastLength.Short).Show ();
}
```

I am getting an error at this line of code:

```
_map.SetOnInfoWindowClickListener (new onInfoWindowClickListener());
```

The error is this:

> Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface
>   'onInfoWindowClickListener'

Can I please have some help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Xamarin Docs for Google Maps](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/maps/part_2_-_maps_api/#2.3.3.info-window-click-events). This should show you exactly how to setup your click listener.

Here is the code that you would want to implement to get your info window click handled properly. the key line is **_map.InfoWindowClick += MapOnInfoWindowClick;**.

```
private bool SetupMapIfNeeded()
{
    if (_map == null)
    {
        _map = _mapFragment.Map;
        if (_map != null)
        {
            _map.InfoWindowClick += MapOnInfoWindowClick;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


private void MapOnInfoWindowClick (object sender, GoogleMap.InfoWindowClickEventArgs e)
{
    Marker myMarker = e.P0;
    // Do something with marker.
}
```